# Notepad++ Search for a <tag> and match till the end of the line

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have some lines like:

```
    <itunes:author>XXX</itunes:author>
    <itunes:subtitle>YYY</itunes:subtitle>
```

I need to remove for example the lines with itunes:autor tag. I tried with "Search" (CTRL+F) - "Regex" selected: `<itunes:author> .*` , but it didn't work. Tried with `itunes:author .*`, no match either. What's the problem? How can I select those lines? Should I escape the < in some way to make the .* "trick" work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach you describe does work:

```
<itunes:author>.*
```

As seen below:

[image: Notepad++ 'find' window]

Comment: I don't know why.. now it magically started working. I can't believe this! -.-

Comment: Might be the space in your regular expression. The expression you put in your question has a space character between "<itunes:author>" and ".*". Notepad++ searches for space character also.

Answer (score 2):

Set search mode to *regular expression* and use this search string `<itunes:author>.*`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't have the ". Matches newline" box checked. I was having the same issue. Once I unchecked it, I was good to go.